# VLCMobileKit does not play RTSP video

Tags: ios, vlc, libvlc

`VLCMobileKit` cannot open RTSP streaming video.

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Create `VLCMedia` with the URI retrieved from the camera
        if let _URI = self.URI, let url = URL(string: _URI) {
            let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
            self.mediaPlayer.media = media
            self.mediaPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

It shows the error:

> VLC is unable to open the MRL
>   'rtsp://193.159.244.134/rtsp_tunnel?profile=0&h26x=4&enableaudio=1&audio_mode=1&vcd=2'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tested the camera from VLC on the desktop or the app using the same MRL?

Comment: I have tried the same URL using the sample on this Pod - https://github.com/rvi/ONVIFCamera (which uses VLCMobileKit to play the stream too)
When I use the ONVIFCamera Pod and try to use VLCMobileKit to play the video, it just doesnot play

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your URL is "protected"(username & password).

If you try this URL:
`rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov`, it should work fine.

Perhaps something like this might work(not tested):

`rtsp://username:password@url`

For example: `rtsp://foo:bar@192.168.1.42/catroom`

Comment: Yes the url is protected and I do supply the username and password but to no avail

Comment: What version of MobileVLCKit are you using?